# The p value of my OPLS-DA model was -nan(ind), I don't know, what's mean, and the residual MS was infinite, I need help here?

Tags: regression, p-value, multivariate-analysis, residuals, orthogonal

[image: The statistic information of my OPLS-DA model]

- I obtained for the first time strange cross-validation results of my OPLS-DA model, the CV ANOVA was -nan(ind), SD residual was inf, MS residual was inf also, moreover, F test equal to zero.

The model was obtained for two groups of samples.